# Indexing stopping abruptly

Tags: solr, lucene

I am facing a problem while indexing in Solr through some cron scripts(PHP). The weird part of the problem is that the scripts and indexing run perfectly when run manually through shell, but stops abruptly when run through cron. The file permissions are all ok.

I did some searching on this problem and so far haven't found any resource that will lead to a solution. I think the problem might be related solr and not the scripts.

I am using solr 4.0. below is the solr indexing log for help. Requesting the audience here to please help. Please let me know if anything is needed from my side.

```
    IFD 0 [Mon May 20 13:55:22 IST 2013; qtp1388338491-15]: init: current segments file is "segments_8aw"; deletionPolicy=org.apache.solr.core.IndexDeletionPolicyWrapper@51507e7
    IFD 0 [Mon May 20 13:55:22 IST 2013; qtp1388338491-15]: init: load commit "segments_8aw"
    IFD 0 [Mon May 20 13:55:22 IST 2013; qtp1388338491-15]: now checkpoint        "_9wv(4.0.0.2):C18890626/1 _9yf(4.0.0.2):C75000/9000 _9y6(4.0.0.2):C85359/8594 _a06(4.0.0.2):C76729/47053 _9z1(4.0.0.2):C25000/5000 _9yy(4.0.0.2):C1000 _a0n(4.0.0.2):C10007/6000 _a0o(4.0.0.2):C1144 _a0p(4.0.0.2):C8869 _a0q(4.0.0.2):C980 _a0r(4.0.0.2):C9009 _a0s(4.0.0.2):C991 _a0t(4.0.0.2):C9011 _a0u(4.0.0.2):C989 _a0v(4.0.0.2):C9013 _a0w(4.0.0.2):C987 _a0x(4.0.0.2):C9014 _a0y(4.0.0.2):C986 _a0z(4.0.0.2):C8015 _a10(4.0.0.2):C1000 _a11(4.0.0.2):C985 _a12(4.0.0.2):C3462" [22 segments ; isCommit = false]
    IW 0 [Mon May 20 13:55:22 IST 2013; qtp1388338491-15]: init: create=false
    IW 0 [Mon May 20 13:55:22 IST 2013; qtp1388338491- 15]:dir=NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/reprtsolr/solr/reply/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@6bf491a6; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0)
    index=_9wv(4.0.0.2):C18890626/1 _9yf(4.0.0.2):C75000/9000 _9y6(4.0.0.2):C85359/8594  _a06(4.0.0.2):C76729/47053 _9z1(4.0.0.2):C25000/5000 _9yy(4.0.0.2):C1000 _a0n(4.0.0.2):C10007/6000 _a0o(4.0.0.2):C1144 _a0p(4.0.0.2):C8869 _a0q(4.0.0.2):C980 _a0r(4.0.0.2):C9009 _a0s(4.0.0.2):C991 _a0t(4.0.0.2):C9011 _a0u(4.0.0.2):C989 _a0v(4.0.0.2):C9013 _a0w(4.0.0.2):C987 _a0x(4.0.0.2):C9014 _a0y(4.0.0.2):C986 _a0z(4.0.0.2):C8015 _a10(4.0.0.2):C1000 _a11(4.0.0.2):C985 _a12(4.0.0.2):C3462
    version=4.0.0 1394950 - rmuir - 2012-10-06 03:00:40
    matchVersion=LUCENE_40
    analyzer=null
    ramBufferSizeMB=320.0
    maxBufferedDocs=-1
    maxBufferedDeleteTerms=-1
    mergedSegmentWarmer=null
    readerTermsIndexDivisor=1
    termIndexInterval=32
    delPolicy=org.apache.solr.core.IndexDeletionPolicyWrapper
    commit=null
    openMode=APPEND
    similarity=org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity
    mergeScheduler=org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler
    default WRITE_LOCK_TIMEOUT=1000
    writeLockTimeout=1000
    codec=Lucene40
    infoStream=org.apache.lucene.util.PrintStreamInfoStream
    mergePolicy=[TieredMergePolicy:maxMergeAtOnce=20,maxMergeAtOnceExplicit=30,maxMergedSegmentMB=5120.0, floorSegmentMB=2.0,forceMergeDeletesPctAllowed=10.0, segmentsPerTier=20.0, useCompoundFile=false, maxCFSSegmentSizeMB=8.796093022207999E12, noCFSRatio=0.1
indexerThreadPool=org.apache.lucene.index.ThreadAffinityDocumentsWriterThreadPool@7c1c2956 readerPooling=false perThreadHardLimitMB=1945
```

Also, the solr server does not throw error when it stops indexing, so I am really not sure why the indexing is breaking.

Comment: Are these logs generated when you index with cron or you don't see any logs when trying to index with?

Comment: These logs are generated when run through cron. Also, I have optimized the cores and ran the same tests again..still no luck!